# Autofac for Service with special test context

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a service constructor:

```
public MyService(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IBaz baz)
```

All these dependencies are handled automatically for my unit tests and the production usage of this service via this Autofac code:

```
public class EntryModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
            .PublicOnly()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Now I need to use an email client in the service:

```
public MyService(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IBaz baz, IEmailClient emailClient)
```

...but invoking it looks like this in the ctor body:

```
_emailClient = new EmailClient(GetSecret("MY_API_KEY").GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

This code works fine since the `GetSecret` call is set up in the proper context (on my machine using port fowarding, etc.) However, when I push this to our build pipelines, it fails because the unit tests don't have the same context to call `GetSecret` and I don't even want a real email client here in the first place, just a mock.

I was trying to pass a `Func` to build the email client, but if I explicitly pass something as a required parameter and manually construct an instance of my service, I'm not using Autofac anymore... and the `Func` is obviously not compile time constant if I make it optional

Is there a way to make Autofac automatically spin up my dependencies for me, and have the right context for both the local context and build pipeline context so the email client can be mocked up in tests, and instantiated with the API key in the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion could be to use Use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder to build a IConfigurationRoot. From a Configuration you can read settings.If you have a CI/CD pipeline it can no doubt set environment variables or api key.

Register an Environment as TEST, PROD or similar

```
 builder.RegisterInstance(configuration).As<IConfigurationRoot>().SingleInstance();
```

Then also register Some Environment and also the EmailClient. Then take email client as dependency in other services. Or register the context you mentioned.
You could also register an EmailClientConfiguration like done with Environment below, and inject  EmailConfiguration the place you need it.

```
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var configuration = c.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
            var environment = configuration.GetSection("Environment").Get<Environment>();
            return environment;
        }).As<IEnvironment>();

        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var environment =  c.Resolve<IEnvironment>();

            switch (environment.EnvironmentName)
            {
                case "Test":
                    return new EmailClient(...);
                case "Dev":
                    return new EmailClient(...);
                case "Prod":
                    return new EmailClient(...);
            }

        }).As<IEmailClient>();
```

This can maybe be done smarter. But this is a viable solution.